# replace character with an increasing number

Tags: python

```
text = "Subjects cover: Warehouse Operations;  effective communication,Speed Functions; Newton laws of motion,Fiber Communication; sea level transmission"
```

How can I use the ";" to replace the previous "," with a number then replace the found ";" with a ":", this is the output I am looking for

```
output="Subjects cover: 1)Warehouse Operations: effective communication 2)Speed Functions: Newton laws of motion 3) Fiber Communication: sea level transmission"
```

i.e where it finds ";" it will go find the previous "," and replace it with a "number)" and then replace the ";" with a ":" after.

I have been trying to do it with regex but the code got very bad & unpythonic.

Comment: I know this is not giving you the code but ideally what I think you should do is split by `;`, iterate and use an increasing number from that iteration and finally join them into one single string. I hope this helps.

Comment: Here it is more or less in a really ugly one-liner.  You can use your imagination from there... `text.split(':')[0] + ': ' + ' '.join(f'{idx + 1}) {txt.strip().replace(":", ";")}' for idx, txt in enumerate(text.split(':')[1].strip().split(',')))`

Comment: @Iguananaut it works if you want to post answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do:

```
text = "Subjects cover: Warehouse Operations;  effective communication,Speed Functions; Newton laws of motion,Fiber Communication; sea level transmission"

# split the string
t1 = text.split(':')

# modify the strings
rf = [[y.replace(';', ':').strip() for y in x.split(',')] for i, x in enumerate(t1[1:])][0]

# join the results
result = t1[0] + ' ' +  ' '.join([f'{i}) {x}' for i,x in enumerate(rf, 1)])

print(result)

'Subjects cover 1) Warehouse Operations:  effective communication 2) Speed Functions: Newton laws of motion 3) Fiber Communication: sea level transmission'
```